# Hibernate, how to count with condition

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am using oracle and hibernate for mapping. I want to count with a condition in count() function. my code is:

```
select count(case when st.averageMark < su.gradePass then 1 else 0 end)
from Study st join st.subject su
 where st.acaYear in (2009)
  and st.semester = 4
  and su.idSeq = 1330
group by st.acaYear
```

the code return me nothing. I used sum instead of count it returned a result but it is wrong, the result is bigger than I suppose it to be.

thank in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just solved the problem with the following code.

```
select sum(case when st.averageMark >= su.gradePass then 1 else 0 end) as pass,
       sum(case when  st.averageMark < su.gradePass then 1 else 0 end) as fail
from Study st join st.subject su
where st.acaYear in (2009) and st.semester = 4 and su.idSeq = 1330
group by st.acaYear
```

Comment: This is working, case is not supported in count, so sum 1 is count and sum 0 is no count. Thanks

Comment: glass it helps.

Answer (score 8):

Combining  [Nathanphan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/647558/nathanphan)'s answer and [M. A. Khomeni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5406023/m-a-khomeni)'s comment,

> `CASE` is not supported in `COUNT()`

So we need to use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`

**For Example:**

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN st.averageMark < su.gradePass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Should be written as

```
SUM(CASE WHEN st.averageMark < su.gradePass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```